# How to remove installation of MySQL on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I need to install older version of mysql server on mac os, but I have a newer version.

I tried to remove this newer installation (5.1), but when start old version install (5.0b) message "MySQL 5.0.51b-community for Mac OS X can't be installed in this disk. A newer version of this software alrady exists on this disk".

I can't recognize problem, because I remove all data of previouse install, but installer says no.

Mac OS version 10.6.

Comment: no. belongs on SO because it's programming related (since mysql is database)

Comment: Same question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x), at roughly the same time it would seem. I posted over there.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try running also

```
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

Comment: This is the one bit missing from most of the other Googleable answers on MySQL uninstallation.

Comment: I actually came across this question while having the same problem with XULRunner, not MySQL, but the answer was the same—removing `/var/db/receipts/org.mozilla.xulrunner.*`.  Thank you!

Comment: I sooo Love Stackoverflow... You saved me bro! Thx a zillion!

Answer (score 23):

Try this, I had to struggle but this works for me!!!!!!!

1. `sudo rm /usr/local/mysql`
2. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*`
3. `sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM`
4. `sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*`
5. (Edit /etc/hostconfig) `sudo vi /etc/hostconfig` (Remove line MYSQLCOM=-YES)
6. `sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*`
7. `sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*`
8. `sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*`

Comment: If you have anything located in the /usr/local/mysql directory this answer provides the most comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 3):

Test finding all files and folders with "mysql" in their name, take a look at them and see if they must be deleted as well.

Use the following command to find all the files.

```
sudo find / | grep -i mysql
```

You can scroll through the output if you put | less at the end (it won't show anything up until it finds something, just so you wouldn't think the command failed.) :-) You can write it as follows.

```
sudo find / | grep -i mysql | less
```

To remove the files/folders, you will have to run the following command (-f means force so you won't be able to restore the files and you won't be asked for a confirmation before they are deleted):

```
sudo rm -rf /path/to/file/or/folder
```

Hope this will be of any help.

Comment: thx for advices :) i do finding stuff on my disk, like you says, but unfortunately output have a lot of information (libs like PHP of Eclipse etc)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can essentially just delete the `/usr/local/mysql-Version/` and unlink the `/usr/local/mysql` directory. Getting rid of the system pref and the start up item might be harder, but I didn't install those so I can't help there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in utility pkgutil to remove the package receipt:

```
sudo pkgutil --forget com.mysql.mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

On Snow Leopard I had to additionally kill mysqld and did

rm /private/var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*

sudo rm -rf /Users//Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Users//Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Users//Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Users//Library/Receipts/MySQL*