# How do you uninstall MySQL from Mac OS X?

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I accidentally installed the PowerPC version of MySQL on my Intel Mac in Snow Leopard, and it installed without a problem but of course doesn't run properly. I just didn't pay enough attention. Now when I try to install the correct x86 version it says that it can't install because a newer version is already installed. A Google query led me to perform these actions/delete these files to uninstall it:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
```

And finally removed the line MYSQLCOM=-YES- from `/etc/hostconfig`

They haven't seemed to help at all. I am still receiving the same message about there being a newer version. I tried installing an even newer version (the current Beta) and it also gave me the same message about a newer version already being installed. I can't uninstall it from the Prefs Pane because I never installed the PrefPane also.

Comment: sudo rm -rf lines with wildcards are a little irresponsible. Especially when you cast the net widely enough to delete anything starting with the letters "My" -- MySQL doesn't have exclusive ownership over the word "My" in its title.

Comment: I'd also suggest backing up /usr/local/mysql/data first -- many people might not realize that that's where mysql keeps its data on mac.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Try running also

```
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

Comment: also `sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM` if it exists

Answer (score 39):

I also had entries in:

```
/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist
```

that i had to delete.

Comment: What kind of entries were these? Hopefully it was just in the older versions but I don't see anything named mysql in there.

Answer (score 36):

If you installed mysql through brew then we can use command to uninstall mysql.

```
$ brew uninstall mysql

Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.19...
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I wish... I'm removing my dmg version from 10.8 so I can install the brew version! :-)

Comment: Also remove "export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin:$PATH"" from ~/.zshrc or ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc.

Comment: worked for me for the default MySQL 8.0.22 for Mojave

Answer (score 21):

```
ps -ax | grep mysql
```

*stop and kill any MySQL processes

```
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup

sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/MySql*

launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

edit `/etc/hostconfig` and remove the line `MYSQLCOM=-YES-`

```
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*    
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

*restart your computer just to ensure any MySQL processes are killed
try to run mysql, it shouldn't work

Comment: I had installed mysql 5.6 using brew. Doing `brew remove mysql` was giving me error: "Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql". So I had to do `brew uninstall mysql@5.6`. Also, I had to remove "export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin:$PATH"" from bash profile (~/.zshrc for my case)

Comment: I . runn brew remove mysql , however I got the error "No available formula or cask with the name "mysql".

Answer (score 15):

OS version: 10.14.6
MYSQL version: 8.0.14

Goto System preferences -> MYSQL[image]

Stop MySQL server

[image]

One option will be shown here to uninstall MYSQL 8 after stopping Mysql server

Answer (score 12):

Aside from the long list of remove commands in your question, which seems quite comprehensive in my recent experience of exactly this issue, I found mysql.sock running in /private/var and removed that.  I used

`find / -name mysql -print 2> /dev/null`

...to find anything that looked like a mysql directory or file and removed most of what came up (aside from Perl/Python access modules).  You may also need to check that the daemon is not still running using Activity Monitor (or at the command line using `ps -A`).  I found that mysqld was still running even after deleting the files.

Comment: You can (and in this case, probably should) use `-iname` if your `find` supports it to perform a case-insensitive search

Answer (score 4):

I also had a config file at /etc/my.cnf that I needed to delete on my Mac OS X Snow Leopard install

Answer (score 4):

It might be overkill but your MySQL command history can also be wiped from:

```
~/.mysql_history
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to identify where MySQL was installed to before attempting to delete it.

I always use the [Hivelogic guide](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/) to installing under Mac OS X which builds MySQL from source. When setting up the build you can specify a directory under which to install MySQL with the **--prefix** parameter. You should make sure the directory does not exist and attempt to install from source.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-extra-charsets=complex \
--enable-thread-safe-client --enable-local-infile --enable-shared \
--with-plugins=innobase
```

Comment: Old answer, I know, but it came up in a [review task](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13972167). Maybe you should add *how* to identify where mysql was installed, not just how to install it. As it is, it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

You should also check /var/db/receipts and remove all entries that contain com.mysql.*

Using sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.* didn't work for me. I had to go into var/db/receipts and delete each one seperately.

Answer (score 1):

I also found

`/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

after using all of the other answers here to uninstall MySQL Community Server 8.0.15 from OS X 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had installed MariaDB years ago using homebrew. Correct uninstall procedure was:
brew uninstall mariadb.

Answer (score 0):

This did the job for me:

```
brew uninstall mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew uninstall --force mysql@<version_no>
```

exmample

```
brew uninstall --force mysql@5.7
```

to get version check cd /usr/local/Cellar

Answer (score -2):

Remove MySQL completely

Open the Terminal

Use `mysqldump` to backup your databases

Check for MySQL processes with:

```
ps -ax | grep mysql
```

Stop and kill any MySQL processes

Analyze MySQL on HomeBrew:

```
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup
```

Remove files:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
```

Unload previous MySQL Auto-Login:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Remove previous MySQL Configuration:

```
subl /etc/hostconfig` 
# Remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
```

Remove previous MySQL Preferences:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

Restart your computer just to ensure any MySQL processes are killed

Try to run mysql, it shouldn't work

Comment: copied from https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d

Answer (score -11):

`sudo find / | grep -i mysql`

This worked like a charm for me. Just went through the list and ensured that anything MySQL related was deleted.

Comment: This ended up being very bad for me, as it found things like the MySQL images that Coda 2 used, as well as some files in Adobe Bridge.

Comment: faster: `sudo find / -iname "*mysql*"`

Comment: This is very bad suggestion. I have ruined my system. It has removed any file that had mysql in their name. It has even corrupted sequel pro and other softwares. Now even though reinstall mysql but I get errors when I try to connect with sequel pro. Please report this answer and have it removed before many more people ruin their computer. And please suggest me what should I do now?