# Installing mysql2 gem for Ruby on Rails with Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard, rubygems

I am having a problem installing the mysql2 gem.

This comes up when I do `gem install mysql2`:

```
Marks-MacBook-Pro:~ Mark$ gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/useruser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/useruser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/useruser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/useruser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Also when I use `rails server` this comes up:

```
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It seems that it cannot find the MySQL library. Have you installed MySQL?
Try installing it via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install mysql
```

or install it via macports or fink or whatever you prefer.

Then try again with:

```
gem install mysql2
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked! Now when I start rails server and click "About your application's env..." This comes up:                               Mysql2::Error

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Rails.root: /Users/useruser/example      Do you know what that means?

Comment: have you setup the mysql server to run?  "mysql.server start" will do the job, and don't forget to configure the access for the root user.

Comment: This comes up:  . ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.

Comment: before any operation you have to execute the "mysql_install_db" command and follow the instructions

Comment: Hi, I getting this problem: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/857/screenshot20110610at230.png/    Can you somebody please help me fix it?    Thank You! :)

Comment: I had the same issue. 1) ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)   2)brew install mysql  3)gem install mysql2

Answer (score 62):

This command worked for me:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

Comment: This one works if you've used the binaries supplied from the mysql website to install it on your Mac.

Comment: thank you, as Guy stated above, this works if you used the mysql website to install

Comment: This worked for me too..but i have not used mysql website to install.

Comment: This worked for me, but I used different directory. I used `locate mysql | grep include` and found another dir. The whole command: `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' -- --srcdir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include`

Comment: i love you so much

Comment: Works on Apple M1, thanks!

Answer (score 29):

Following command worked for me successfully.

> x.x.x = version of mysql2 you want to install.

```
gem install mysql2 -v 'x.x.x' -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me me after I installed MariaDB 10.2 (via brew) on macOS 10.12.5, Ruby 2.3.4, Rails 5.0.3

Comment: quick note for OSX 10.13.5 and mysql installed through homebrew:
--srcdir is: `/usr/local/include/mysql`

Answer (score 20):

I don't need MySQL on Mac OS X, because I have MySQL installed on Vagrant box. Therefore, I just installed mysql-connector-c.

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
gem install mysql2
```

Answer (score 7):

To fix for a manual gem install:

```
brew install openssl
gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"
```

To fix for all bundle installs:

```
brew install openssl
bundle config --global build.mysql2 --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"
bundle install
```

Comment: Only this one worked for me!

Comment: Today's life saver!

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me

```
brew install mysql 
brew install mysql-connector-c
gem install mysql2
```

Answer (score 4):

If you used **homebrew** to install mysql, `brew install mysql`,this worked for me:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 'x.x.x' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/y.y.y/bin/mysql_config
```

x.x.x = version of the mysql2 gem you want to install
y.y.y = the version of mysql you have installed `ls /usr/local/Cellar/mysql` to find it.

to get the version of mysql

```
brew info mysql                                                                                                                                                                                                     
mysql: stable 5.7.19 (bottled)
               ...
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19 (322 files, 233MB) *

               ...
```

then if you want to install with bundle:

```
bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/y.y.y/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: I love you! 'u save my life :D

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to specify some additional environment variables to install this gem on the 64 bit architecture for Mac OSX 10.6:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2
```

If you are using rvm you can add this as your default option in the ~/.rvmrc file:

```
rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"
```

Comment: didn't work :( Maybe I am doing it wrong, can you explain a bit more in detail how to do it please?

Comment: Did you get the same error or a different error? If you have your mysql installed somewhere other than the default you might also need to specify other flags like --with-opt-dir as well.

Comment: I am getting the same error. It says: Gem files will remain installed in /Users/useruser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection. Maybe that can help? and yes I am using rvm

Comment: I have fixed the problem in the question with help from you and ALoR. Thank you for formatting my question! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and errors trying to install mysql2. I thought my mamp install of MySQL would work fine and spent a few hours playing around with paths to get that to work - no success.

Finally came across this post from ALoR and installed a fresh version through homebrew - however - be sure to follow ALL the instructions from homebrew! I missed a few steps and wasted another hour tracking down that problem - here are those instructions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11061487/1241271

After MySQL was successfully installed, I ran: `sudo gem install mysql2` and it worked like a charm.

Hope this helps someone from wasting several hours because they neglected to read the docs (newb mistake).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure openssl is installed on Mac via Homebrew.

```
brew install openssl

Install mysql2 gem.

gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/i
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 'x.x.x' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

- x.x.x: replace it with the mysql2 gem version you want to install

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered multiple times however, here's what's working for me with:
May 20, 2019
OSX Mojave 10.14.4
MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin17]
Rails 5.2.1

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.7/5.7.24/bin/mysql_config
```

change "/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.24/bin/mysql_config" to whatever your current valid path is from "/usr/local/Cellar/mysql"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after upgrading to Catalina (10.15.x)

My Gemfile.lock has defined mysql2-0.3.20, which I could not get installed. 
But it worked, when I upgraded it to mysql2-0.5.2

```
gem update mysql2 -- --srcdir=/usr/local/include/mysql/
```

Be sure that you have installed mysql with brew.

```
brew install mysql
brew link mysql
```

(Linking /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18... 95 symlinks created)

However, after this the gem mysql2 was installed, but the bundle update mysql2 didn't work.

But this other answer helped me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39628463/110214

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

bundle update mysql2
```