# Why can't I install mysql2 on Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I don't know how to install mysql2.

I'm using:

- Ruby On Rails 3.2.14
- Ruby 2.0.0
- Mac OS X 10.9 ("Mavericks")

---

```
Installing mysql2 (0.3.13) 

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kimingi/.bundler/tmp/1983/gems/mysql2-0.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kimingi/.bundler/tmp/1983/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.

ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Comment: Do you install the libmysqlclient-dev first?

Comment: One of the problems with living on the bleeding edge of OS versions is you inherit the problems of porting existing code to work on the unknown/new code-base. Installers test for known versions and often vomit badly with unknown ones.

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409761/installing-mysql2-gem-for-ruby-on-rails-with-mac-osx-10-6

Answer (score 5):

You need to install mysql locally. Since you're on OS X you can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

```
# to Install homebrew
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"

# to install mysql through homebrew
brew install mysql
```

Comment: You might add more information about how to install homebrew since it's not a normal part of a Mac OS installation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same problem. To fix this problem, open a command prompt. go to your application folder. And type: gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.11  this version is working great.