# Why is my rake db:migrate failing to respond?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I tried typing in rake db:migrate to create a migration, but my rake is aborted and giving me this statement. Could you please explain why this is happening?

```
Muhammeds-MacBook-Pro:simple_cms muhammedz786$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/muhammedz786/rails_application/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/muhammedz786/rails_application/simple_cms/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: do you have `libmysqlclient` or `libmysqlclient-dev`  not install those

Comment: How can I download these?

Comment: which os you are using

Comment: He's using a Mac.  You may be able to get them on http://www.opensource.apple.com/ by clicking on your Mac version.

Answer (score 1):

your mysql package not install properly for that give command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

if this is not work install this

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: when I type it in my computer I get "sudo: apt-get: command not found" why is that happening?

Comment: if this show that then how did you installed mysql in your computer before, can you plesase send me that command

Comment: in your computer there is not apt-get package please first install it.

Comment: i downloaded mysql via "brew install mysql" command on the terminal

Comment: ok you have another flavor of ubuntu.. so you use this commad to install that above packages

Comment: It's a Mac not Ubuntu or a Linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I see you are on a Macintosh.  Therefore, try the following:

1. Run `mysql_install_db` in the terminal
2. Run `mysql.server start` in the terminal
3. If that doesn't work checkout [Installing mysql2 gem for Ruby on Rails with Mac OSX 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409761/installing-mysql2-gem-for-ruby-on-rails-with-mac-osx-10-6)