# RoR: Fail on 'gem install mysql2' on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2, osx-yosemite

- I am on OS X Yosemite (10.10.3)
- I have installed mysql via Homebrew

I get the following error when I run bundle on my project

[image]

Comment: Did you try running `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` like the error message suggests?

Comment: I did, it outputs the same result

Comment: What's the full error that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` outputs? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message instead of including an image. This is a common problem reported on stack overflow, and quite a few have working answers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758945/cant-install-mysql2-on-mac-os-10-9 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409761/installing-mysql2-gem-for-ruby-on-rails-with-mac-osx-10-6 for instance.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy I understand it's a common problem. And all those links provide the same answer which I have already tried.

Comment: @JoeKennedy, sorry I fixed the problem before I could get to error again.

Answer (score 0):

My recent upgrade to yosemite might be causing the problem. I had xcode version 6.3, which I downgraded to 6.2 and tried bundle and it worked!