# How to workaround 'library not found' errors when installing mysql2 in Mac

Tags: macos, mysql2

I'm trying to install mysql2 in my Mac running on MacOS Big Sur. When I run 'gem install mysql2' I get:
library not found for -lzstd

If I then run 'gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix zstd)"' I get:
library not found for -lssl

I can then run 'gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"' but I again get:
library not found for -lzstd

How can I workaround this issue? Is there a way to specify both libraries with 'with-opt-dir'?

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/13799101/9319119
After I downloaded mysql from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=508096 I was able to just run gem install mysql2 -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include