# Mysql start up issues | ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, macos

Any Ideas?

```
Joshs-MacBook-Pro:cdwhp joshc$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Joshs-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).
```

Error Logs

```
120927 13:08:35 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120927 13:08:36 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
120927 13:08:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120927 13:08:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120927 13:08:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120927 13:08:36 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120927 13:08:36 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120927 13:08:36 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120927 13:08:36  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120927 13:08:37 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 9531786
120927 13:08:37 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.27/bin/mysqld: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'
120927 13:08:37 [ERROR] Aborting

120927 13:08:37  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120927 13:08:37  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 9531786
120927 13:08:37 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.27/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120927 13:08:37 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Joshs-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
```

Comment: It looks like you installed mysql using homebrew. Where is the location of your error logs? I'm having a similar problem but can't find the log location.

Comment: look at another question for exact answer http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The option `default-character-set` was removed in MySQL 5.5.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-character-set).

You should change it in `my.cnf` to the alternative;

> [character-set-server=utf8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_character-set-server)

Comment: Where can I find `my.cnf`? @Joachim Isaksson

Comment: Its inside /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc folder

Answer (score 44):

Complete reinstall of mysql solved this problem in my case:

```
brew uninstall mysql
rm -Rf /usr/local/var/mysql
brew install mysql
mysql.server start
```

Note: use this as last resort, all data will be deleted

Comment: this doesn't delete your data?

Comment: Does this delete all your data? or just the software?

Comment: PHEWPH. Thank you @Vladimir

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same problem. I was doing

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

What I really should have been doing was running the command as my user (not su)

```
mysql.server start
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Exactly!
here also when I ran the command without "sudo" it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps but, I was having the same issue after I accidentally left mysql server running for a few days. I was getting 
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/[NAS].pid).

I was able to fix it by typing

`sudo kill 10191`   - the process number for mysql on my computer

Then started up mysql again and it worked like fine. I hope this helps someone out of the same jam.

Answer (score 1):

I found the log in `bogon.log`

> InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A
>   new tablespace will be created! 2016-03-27T14:45:36.200398Z 0 [ERROR]
>   InnoDB: redo log file './ib_logfile0' exists. Creating system
>   tablespace with existing redo log files is not recommended. Please
>   delete all redo log files before creating new system tablespace. `

so I `delete` the `ib*` and `mysql.server restart`, that's work

Answer (score 1):

use

```
`mysql.server status;` - tells you the process number/s 

`sudo kill ######;` - enter process number repeat as needed

`mysql.server start;` - start everything up again
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Somehow the files `YourComputerName.pid` and "YourComputerName.err" in `/usr/local/mysql/data` were created under _mysql user. I just removed those files and started the sql server with the following command `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

Answer (score -1):

delete file `/usr/local/var/mysql/*********.local.err` 
run `mysql.server start`