# MySQL can not start after I changed the my.cnf

Tags: mysql, macos

I copy the `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf` to `/etc/my.cnf`, and changed it contents to :

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
default-character-set=utf8
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

But then my MySQL can not start now:

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

1. In the before, there is no `my.cnf`, so the MySQL use the default configruation.
2. the `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf` only has this line :

   ```
   [mysqld]
   sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
   ```

other lines all be commented.

I only changed to the upper code.

---

**EDIT-2**

I use the command(`sudo $(ps auxww|sed -n '/sed -n/d;/mysqld /{s/.* \([^ ]*mysqld\) .*/\1/;p;}') --verbose --help|grep '^log'`) get the bellow messages:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:etc ldl$ sudo $(ps auxww|sed -n '/sed -n/d;/mysqld /{s/.* \([^ ]*mysqld\) .*/\1/;p;}') --verbose --help|grep '^log'
log-bin                                                      (No default value)
log-bin-index                                                (No default value)
log-bin-trust-function-creators                              FALSE
log-bin-use-v1-row-events                                    FALSE
log-builtin-as-identified-by-password                        FALSE
log-error                                                    stderr
log-error-verbosity                                          1
log-isam                                                     myisam.log
log-output                                                   FILE
log-queries-not-using-indexes                                FALSE
log-raw                                                      FALSE
log-short-format                                             FALSE
log-slave-updates                                            FALSE
log-slow-admin-statements                                    FALSE
log-slow-slave-statements                                    FALSE
log-statements-unsafe-for-binlog                             TRUE
log-syslog                                                   FALSE
log-syslog-facility                                          daemon
log-syslog-include-pid                                       TRUE
log-syslog-tag                                               
log-tc                                                       tc.log
log-tc-size                                                  24576
log-throttle-queries-not-using-indexes                       0
log-timestamps                                               UTC
log-warnings                                                 0
```

Comment: could you provide us more information? What is the error in the mysql log

Comment: Show complete old `my.cnf` and new `my.cnf`. Add mysql-log.

Comment: @BitAccesser the `/var/log/` do not have mysql's logs, where it is.

Comment: Have a websearch "osx mysql log location" to find [where-is-my-mysql-log-on-os-x](https://serverfault.com/questions/42531/where-is-my-mysql-log-on-os-x). The use of `OS X`should be clearly explained at top of question.

Comment: Check if there is a syntax error in your 'my.cnf' file

Comment: @BitAccesser Because the MySQL can not start up, so I can not use that method.

Comment: Use your old `my.cnf`!

Comment: @BitAccesser Yeah! How could I not think.

Comment: `default-character-set=utf8` is [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627604/mysql-start-up-issues-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file?answertab=oldest#tab-top)!

Comment: The errors are logged to `stderr`which is console in your case. Start mysqld from shell, then you should see the errors or use [--log-error=file_name](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-safe.html#option_mysqld_safe_log-error) option for creating a error log file