# MySQL error with homebrew on OSX 10.8

Tags: mysql, sockets, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, pid

I've tried every solution posted here after running brew install mysql, and still no luck. On trying to start MySQL I get this:

```
me$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/cpe-98-14-179.159.nyc.res.rr.com.pid).
```

Or this:

```
me$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)
```

etc/my.cnf looks like this:

```
me$ sudo nano etc/my.cnf
Password:

[mysqld]
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock


[mysql.server]
user=mysql
basedir=/usr/local/mysql


[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Are my permissions wrong? Is it possible my directories are messed up? If I could wipe everything clean and install from the website I'd try that at this point. Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Comment: check out the **Related** links on the right side... There is so much info...

Comment: http://sqlhjalp.blogspot.fi/2012/11/the-server-quit-without-updating-pid.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error. Trying everything, including the stuff referenced by Casper above, and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R user_name /usr/local/var/mysql/
```

Replace user_name with your user name.