# PID file could not be found - The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, osx-mavericks

I have install MySQL from pkg installer on my mac, When I try to start it using this command

```
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

It gives me following error:

```
The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/xyz.local.pid)
```

Upon checking error log, I found this

```
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/xyz.local.pid ended
```

Well I have tried every possible solution out there, I have followed related question here 
[Missing PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file) still I am unable to resolve this issue.

Here is how `my.cnf` looks like

```
[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

I have also tried installing MySQL with `Macports`, still the same issue.

Comment: Did you use `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart` or else start it from a root shell? It will fail with an error about the PID file if you try to start it from a non-superuser shell.

Comment: Yes I did that.Actually the issue was with Macports, I reinstalled MacPorts, Installed MySQL again and it worked.
Thanks anyway.