# Starting MySQL ....... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, laravel, osx-mavericks

I am currently in the process of getting up and running with Laravel, on a Mac, with OSX Mavericks.

I am following this tutorial to set up my AMP environment: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-9-mavericks/

Everything is fine until the MySQL step: I downloaded the latest DMG file here:http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and installed it.

However, when I try to start MySQL in the terminal, I get the following message:

```
Starting MySQL ....... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
```

Also, when I try to start MySQL from the Preferences panel, the computer seems to try and start it, but eventually won't.

So, two questions:

1. Do you have any idea of what is going wrong?
2. For previous projects, I had to install MAMP and Ruby on Rails: could any of these cause any incompatibility with MySQL?

Thank you.

Comment: Try using homebrew http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file

Comment: seriously recommend [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) for your local environments. You will encounter many less errors while not screwing with your mac.

Comment: Thanks @NoahMatisoff. I did try to install it with Homebrew, everything seemed to be fine, but I keep getting the same error:

mysql.server restart
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
.... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Comment: @JaredEitnier: in the tutorial I am following — Up and running with Laravel, from Lynda.com — the instructor recommends to install all AMP components separately/independentaly. Would Vagrant let me do that?

Comment: Thibaud Vagrant is its own virtual machine it's a complete fresh install.  Read about Laravel Homestead it's pretty amazing http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

Comment: The homestead vagrant box is highly optimized for PHP sites, specifically Laravel and requires little configuration. It beats messing around with configuring all the components separately by far.

Answer (score 1):

`ps aux | grep mysql`

And then

`kill -9 {number returned from above}`

And then

`service mysqld restart`