# How to start mysql server on osx?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have very popular problem with mysql but after 2 days googling, I didn't find way to solve it.

After trying to start server, I got this error:

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
>   (/usr/local/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro-Medved.local.pid).

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Which solutions explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file did you try and what was the respective outcome?

Comment: sure
And I've tried to create this file: MacBook-Pro-Medved.local.pid
Also I've tried many solution from google search, but anything helped me

Comment: /usr/local/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro-Medved.local.err - show me:
Permission denied