# The server quit without updating PID file.Mysql

Tags: mysql

On Yosemite, starting MySQL gives the following error:

The server quit without updating PID file

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file) question here and i have found the solution

```
           sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/
```

But Can anyone please explain me why this solved the problem?
And why the problem was raised in the first place?

Comment: Item #2 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8137439/62576) to the post you linked explained why it solves the problem. What part of that isn't clear?

Answer (score 0):

mysqld creates a "PID file" that contains the Process ID of the mysqld process. It will refuse to start if that file exists, because that usually means mysqld is still running. In this case, however, mysqld was forcefully stopped and had no chance to delete its PID file. Running `sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/` will delete it, but don't do that unless you *know* there's no other mysqld processes running. (ProTip™: Find the PID in the PID file then `kill` it to make sure. I am not responsible for any losses with that method (especially killing another process other than MySQL).)