# MySQL not running on Linux machine

Tags: mysql, linux, pid

I tried everything and I am still unable to start the MySQL service. The error is as below:

```
[root@localhost ~]# service mysql.server start Starting MySQL..... 
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid).
[root@localhost ~]# service mysql start Starting MySQL....
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid).
```

Things I tried:

Removing the .err file and restarting, no use. Creating a .sock file and a .pid file as the above error mentions, still no use. Almost tried all the steps in most of the forums, still nothing.

I tried all the config files, nothing seems to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next steps:

**First remove MySQL:**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

**Then reinstall:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo mysql_install_db
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

After these steps mysql process should be up and running. Anyway, if this is not happening ( you can verify by typing `sudo service mysql status` ) just try:

`sudo service mysql start` or `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

I strongly reccommend to post your log files (`/var/log/syslog`) for mysql if you get any problems, so that we can advice you properly.

If you're still getting the same error, please check for svs answer from **[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file)**

Comment: Hello Alexander,

Thank you for the prompt response, I did try to remove it completely and I am not going to lie it failed. But I am new to this so could you give me a different command to uninstall Mysql completely from my CentOS server.. I think i managed to del only the previous version and not the components or stuff like configurations ,etc.

Basically i am trying to tell you  that I do not have apt-get functionality  , so could i completely remove Mysql using a different command.

Comment: And yes for your log :
[root@localhost log]# tail -200f mysqld.log 
150817 11:30:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150817 11:30:52 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.45) starting as process 32097 ...
150817 11:30:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150817 11:30:52 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150817 11:30:52 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150817 11:30:52 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

Comment: 150817 11:30:52 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150817 11:30:52 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150817 11:30:52 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
150817 11:30:52 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150817 11:30:52 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150817 11:30:52 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150817 11:30:52 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: 150817 11:30:52 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete