# MYSQL error, cannot start service and mysql.sock not found

Tags: mysql, ssh, putty

Yesterday, my website crashed. Or, what appears to be a crash.

My host (JustHost) have disclosed that it was a SAN problem and have been rebuilding it. It's hard to get anymore information out of them because they are playing their cards very close to their chest for some reason.

I have suffered almost 24 hours downtime in 2 days and I'm getting fed up.

The error I am receiving on the frontend of the website is:

```
Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.Database     connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.
```

Trying to access my phpMyadmin from cPanel gives me the following error:
[image]

Accessing SSH and trying to start the mysql service via putty I get:

```
Starting MySQL. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql        /mysqld.pid).
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue as my host is rather useless!

Thanks!

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file) might be of help

Comment: Thanks for the link. Won't that install a new DB? Does this mean that my old DB has been lost? @vmachan

Comment: I think the second answer in the post that begins with "try to find your log file with suffix ".err" "  does not involve re-installing and would not lose any data. I think there is more info. it indicates that you would need to check for the PID file and error files and removing those and then trying to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, mysqld is down. Did you try running "mysqld_safe&"?

Comment: Just tried that: "
160107 23:19:06 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/server.***.err'.
160107 23:19:06 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160107 23:19:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid ended" @Phil Smith

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wishes to know the conclusion of this issue.

I have been left with 2 choices:
1) Be patient and wait for Just Host to fix the issue and potentially lose my Google search rankings and a lot more future revenue
2) Set up a new hosting account, transfer my data over and wait for the domain to propagate.

I have chosen the latter of the two. My confidence in Just Host as a customer service hub and web hosting provider has thoroughly diminished to the point where all of my hosting accounts will now be switched over to another provider.

They have let me down by not fixing the issue in good time and have passed me from pillar to post in live chat, email support and phone support. The final nail in the coffin was my request for them to backup my databases and send them to me via email being met with the resoundingly passive "sorry, we do not provide that service" response.

I would do it myself if only I had access to phpMyadmin, which I do not have because of a server error that they have been incapable of fixing for the past 72 hours.

Goodbye Just Host.