# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file - mysql56 via brew

Tags: mysql

```
160112 08:49:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2016-01-12 08:49:30 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-01-12 08:49:30 0 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.27/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27) starting as process 62810 ...
2016-01-12 08:49:30 62810 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2016-01-12 08:49:30 62810 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
00:49:30 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68101 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fff57e48f00
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fff57e489a0 thread_stack 0x40000
0   mysqld                              0x0000000108066665 my_print_stacktrace + 61
1   mysqld                              0x0000000107eb5db2 handle_fatal_signal + 696
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff848bb52a _sigtramp + 26
3   mysqld                              0x00000001086464c8 PSI_server + 0
4   mysqld                              0x0000000107fcfae9 _Z14open_table_defP3THDP11TABLE_SHAREj + 4816
5   mysqld                              0x0000000107ee80ff _Z15get_table_shareP3THDP10TABLE_LISTPKcjjPij + 448
6   mysqld                              0x0000000107eeb27b _Z10open_tableP3THDP10TABLE_LISTP18Open_table_context + 2019
7   mysqld                              0x0000000107eed68b _Z11open_tablesP3THDPP10TABLE_LISTPjjP19Prelocking_strategy + 1252
8   mysqld                              0x0000000107eedfcc _Z20open_and_lock_tablesP3THDP10TABLE_LISTbjP19Prelocking_strategy + 50
9   mysqld                              0x0000000107f617a5 _Z11plugin_initPiPPci + 2678
10  mysqld                              0x0000000107ff7fa6 _Z11mysqld_mainiPPc + 2674
11  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8896d5ad start + 1
12  ???                                 0x0000000000000007 0x0 + 7

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160112 08:49:30 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Services-iMac.local.pid ended
160112 08:49:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2016-01-12 08:49:43 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-01-12 08:49:43 0 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.27/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27) starting as process 62980 ...
2016-01-12 08:49:43 62980 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2016-01-12 08:49:43 62980 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
00:49:43 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68101 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fff573c1f00
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fff573c19a0 thread_stack 0x40000
0   mysqld                              0x0000000108aed665 my_print_stacktrace + 61
1   mysqld                              0x000000010893cdb2 handle_fatal_signal + 696
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff848bb52a _sigtramp + 26
3   mysqld                              0x00000001090cd4c8 PSI_server + 0
4   mysqld                              0x0000000108a56ae9 _Z14open_table_defP3THDP11TABLE_SHAREj + 4816
5   mysqld                              0x000000010896f0ff _Z15get_table_shareP3THDP10TABLE_LISTPKcjjPij + 448
6   mysqld                              0x000000010897227b _Z10open_tableP3THDP10TABLE_LISTP18Open_table_context + 2019
7   mysqld                              0x000000010897468b _Z11open_tablesP3THDPP10TABLE_LISTPjjP19Prelocking_strategy + 1252
8   mysqld                              0x0000000108974fcc _Z20open_and_lock_tablesP3THDP10TABLE_LISTbjP19Prelocking_strategy + 50
9   mysqld                              0x00000001089e87a5 _Z11plugin_initPiPPci + 2678
10  mysqld                              0x0000000108a7efa6 _Z11mysqld_mainiPPc + 2674
11  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8896d5ad start + 1
12  ???                                 0x0000000000000007 0x0 + 7

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160112 08:49:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Services-iMac.local.pid ended
➜  mysql git:(master) sudo kill -9 62810
kill: 62810: No such process
➜  mysql git:(master) sudo cat Services-iMac.local.err
160112 08:49:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2016-01-12 08:49:30 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-01-12 08:49:30 0 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.27/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27) starting as process 62810 ...
2016-01-12 08:49:30 62810 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2016-01-12 08:49:30 62810 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
00:49:30 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68101 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fff57e48f00
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fff57e489a0 thread_stack 0x40000
0   mysqld                              0x0000000108066665 my_print_stacktrace + 61
1   mysqld                              0x0000000107eb5db2 handle_fatal_signal + 696
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff848bb52a _sigtramp + 26
3   mysqld                              0x00000001086464c8 PSI_server + 0
4   mysqld                              0x0000000107fcfae9 _Z14open_table_defP3THDP11TABLE_SHAREj + 4816
5   mysqld                              0x0000000107ee80ff _Z15get_table_shareP3THDP10TABLE_LISTPKcjjPij + 448
6   mysqld                              0x0000000107eeb27b _Z10open_tableP3THDP10TABLE_LISTP18Open_table_context + 2019
7   mysqld                              0x0000000107eed68b _Z11open_tablesP3THDPP10TABLE_LISTPjjP19Prelocking_strategy + 1252
8   mysqld                              0x0000000107eedfcc _Z20open_and_lock_tablesP3THDP10TABLE_LISTbjP19Prelocking_strategy + 50
9   mysqld                              0x0000000107f617a5 _Z11plugin_initPiPPci + 2678
10  mysqld                              0x0000000107ff7fa6 _Z11mysqld_mainiPPc + 2674
11  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8896d5ad start + 1
12  ???                                 0x0000000000000007 0x0 + 7

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160112 08:49:30 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Services-iMac.local.pid ended
160112 08:49:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2016-01-12 08:49:43 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-01-12 08:49:43 0 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.27/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27) starting as process 62980 ...
2016-01-12 08:49:43 62980 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2016-01-12 08:49:43 62980 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
00:49:43 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68101 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fff573c1f00
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fff573c19a0 thread_stack 0x40000
0   mysqld                              0x0000000108aed665 my_print_stacktrace + 61
1   mysqld                              0x000000010893cdb2 handle_fatal_signal + 696
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff848bb52a _sigtramp + 26
3   mysqld                              0x00000001090cd4c8 PSI_server + 0
4   mysqld                              0x0000000108a56ae9 _Z14open_table_defP3THDP11TABLE_SHAREj + 4816
5   mysqld                              0x000000010896f0ff _Z15get_table_shareP3THDP10TABLE_LISTPKcjjPij + 448
6   mysqld                              0x000000010897227b _Z10open_tableP3THDP10TABLE_LISTP18Open_table_context + 2019
7   mysqld                              0x000000010897468b _Z11open_tablesP3THDPP10TABLE_LISTPjjP19Prelocking_strategy + 1252
8   mysqld                              0x0000000108974fcc _Z20open_and_lock_tablesP3THDP10TABLE_LISTbjP19Prelocking_strategy + 50
9   mysqld                              0x00000001089e87a5 _Z11plugin_initPiPPci + 2678
10  mysqld                              0x0000000108a7efa6 _Z11mysqld_mainiPPc + 2674
11  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8896d5ad start + 1
12  ???                                 0x0000000000000007 0x0 + 7

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160112 08:49:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Services-iMac.local.pid ended
```

Trying to start `mysql` doesn't load it.

```
➜  mysql git:(master) mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Services-iMac.local.pid).
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file)

Comment: Got this exact error too on El Cap.

Comment: Does this help? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/downgrading.html#downgrade-methods

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me after re-installing mysql.
I originally installed the default version (mysql 5.7.x), but downgraded back to mysql56.

The issue may lie on the unclean shutdown of 5.7 as I issued a `brew uninstall mysql` while my launchd-managed mysqld instance was running. The symlinks, data, and old 5.7.x-related stuff were not cleaned thoroughly.

As to the error, the solution so far was to follow the recommendation here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70431, and i.e. adding the `skip-grant-tables` in your my.cnf (create one under /etc if you don't have one)