# Getting "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock'" (2) mysql on El Capitan

Tags: mysql, sockets, homebrew, osx-elcapitan, mysql-error-2002

I know that this question has already been submitted many times. Yet, all the solutions seem to be a bit out-of-date or not in line with the current version of mysql.

So, I've tried to install Mysql 5.7.11 on El Capitan via Homebrew. When I launch

```
mysql -u root
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Few insights from other solutions..

- I looked for my.cnf and it's empty
- If I try to launch `mysql.server start` I get `. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/MacBook-Air-2.local.pid).` (Where MacBook-Air-2 is my HOSTNAME)

Any idea? I'm really stuck here for days now and I don't know what else to try!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file)

Comment: my.cnf is empty... it doesn't seem to be the same situation, unfortunately..

Comment: and actually if I launch `mdfind -name "my.cnf"` this is the result: many file in mysql-test `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/mysql-test/suite/ndbcluster/my.cnf` and then `/Users/stEo/my.cnf` and `/private/etc/my.cnf`