# MySQL 5.7 Won't Start on OS X Sierra 10.12

Tags: mysql

I've tried every post about this problem on Stack Exchange. None have worked.

I started with OS X El Capitan and had similar issues
Upgraded to Sierra thinking it might help....oops.
I have tried reinstalling using the DMG from MySQL.
I have tried changing permissions according to directions on other StackExchange posts.
I have tried killing running instances of MySQL.
I have tried changing ownership of files according to directions on other StackExchange posts.
I have tried installing with HomeBrew.
I have tried installing older versions of MySQL.
I have tried creating pid and conf files by hand.
I have tried deleting .err files in the data directory.

Nothing has seemed to work for me.

Attempting to start a fresh install of MySQL 5.7 on OS X Sierra 10.12 yields the following results:

```
~ /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start 
Starting MySQL
./usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 133: /usr/local/mysql/data/Scotts-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 133: /usr/local/mysql/data/Scotts-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 178: /usr/local/mysql/data/Scotts-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 133: /usr/local/mysql/data/Scotts-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Scotts-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried run it as sudo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file) That post gives you many *ideas* of what you can try, and you've shown none of those efforts here in your post. What **specifically** have you tried from **every post about this problem** that hasn't worked for you?

Comment: @KenWhite - I added an explanation to show the things I've tried to fix the issue. Can you please reconsider the down vote, or allow us to delete the question? We deleted the hard drive and reinstalled OS X and it works now. That's the only way I was able to make it work.

Comment: I've removed the downvote. As long as you don't have upvoted answers, you're always free to delete your own posts. There's a link to do so under the tags. (A full disk wipe and OS install is hardly the proper solution, but I'm glad you got things sorted out.) You may want to read [ask] before your next question here.