# mysql server start: server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql

I've tried nearly every solution I could find on StackOverflow related to this question, but I can't seem to get any of them to work for me.

I am developing on my local computer with Ruby. When I launch my Ruby server, I get an error saying:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

When I have seen this error in the past, all I have done to remedy is close my Rails server, and run the simple command:

`mysql.server start`

However, now when I run that command I receive the following error message:

`ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Peters-MacBook-Air.local.pid).`

I would really appreciate any help sorting this out! I've tried looking for other solutions for about 2 hours and can't get any of them to work. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your MySQL installation is trashed. Check the MySQL error logs, wherever those are.

Comment: [Have you tried this previous post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file)

Comment: Was able to solve using this post, but required completely wiping my databases. Not ideal. https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks