# Cannot start MySQL on Mac - Permission denied

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to run MySQL installed through HomeBrew on a Mac (High Sierra) but I am always having these problems of permissions and with the PID file. I have tried hundreds of possible solutions I found online, but I could not fix these issues:

```
Haline:/ Haline$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
./usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/Haline.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/Haline.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199: /usr/local/var/mysql/Haline.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/Haline.local.err: Permission denied
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Haline.local.pid).
```

Can anyone help me, pleeease?

Comment: It would indicate a file permissions problem. Check that the user running the command has the correct permissions/groups for these files and `chmod/chown` as necessary.

Answer (score 10):

According to the official [troubleshooting page of Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting.html):

> If commands fail with permissions errors, check the permissions of /usr/local’s subdirectories. If you’re unsure what to do, you can run `cd /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami) bin etc include lib sbin share var opt Cellar Caskroom Frameworks`.

Alternatively, if you have not installed applications in `/usr/local` that rely on specific permissions, you can also run:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
```

Comment: That did it for me! On Apple silicon use cd /opt/homebrew/ && sudo chown -R $(whoami) bin etc include lib sbin share var opt Cellar Caskroom Frameworks instead, as Homebrew installs to a different directory than previously

Comment: this along with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55157844/3852169
brought end to my 2 hours struggle in finding useless logs!!

Comment: sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/homebrew/* also works on me

Comment: Excellent! Fixed my issue!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem on Mac Sonoma. The following steps solved the issue for me:

```
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
uninstall mysql
install mysql
```

`mysql.server start` should work now

Comment: This is not working!!!