# cant run the mysql shell when running specific version of mysql from brew

Tags: mysql, homebrew

in my brew I have 2 mysql versions:

```
mysql installed versions: 5.7.20_1, 8.0.11
```

I switch to `5.7.20_1`, type `mysql.server start` and all good, I can type `mysql` hit enter and im in the shell.

now, I switch to `8.0.11` type `mysql.server start` and get:

```
Starting MySQL
.... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/My-MBP-2.pid).
```

I can only start `8.0.11` version with `brew services start mysql` but then i dont know how to open its shell...so confused. just wanted to upgrade from `5.7.20_1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file)

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file