# Unable to start mysql 5.6 on Mac

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, sequelpro

I installed mysql 5.6 using homebrew but haven't been able to start it/login using Sequel pro.

When I run `mysql.server start` in the terminal I am getting this error -

```
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
```

I had installed mysql 8 first,but uninstalled it since I needed 5.6
My prefPane was showing an instance of mysql 8 but not showing any instance now.
The activity monitor isnt showing `mysqld` so doesn't look like mysql is running.
My OS is High Sierra

Comment: Do any of the other answers for that error help?  Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file

Comment: Am unable to locate the error file which is mentioned in most answers

Comment: I dont have this folder since I used homebrew -- /usr/local/var/mysql

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem on Mojave and the error was around "unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'" when I attempted to get 5.6 running using Homebrew. I couldn't figure out how to sort this out so eventually switched to the official [Mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-osx-excerpt/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html) and installed version 5.7 using the dmg version and that worked like a charm. (since 5.6 wasn't available for macOS at the time of writing)