# Mysql server 8 error at startup: "The server quit without updating PID file"

Tags: mysql

On my Macbook Pro with macOS 10.14.3 Mojave, I am installing mysql server 8.0.15 using homebrew like so:

```
brew install mysql
```

However, after I have done that, it cannot be started and gives the following error message:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/<hostname>.local.pid).
```

I have tried numerous times to remove then reinstall, both trough

```
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup
brew install mysql
```

and

```
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup
brew reinstall mysql
```

The result is always the same.

I know there is a [similar thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file), but it seems to refer mysql 5.X, and the remedies suggested in that thread do not work or do not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that

```
brew remove mysql
```

did not remove all instances of mysql. There were still an instance from a previous installation installed in `/usr/local/mysql/` which interfered with the new installation.

So

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql/*
```

followed by

```
brew install mysql
```

solved the problem.