# What is the default port number of MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

What is the default port number of MariaDB?

I am new to programming. I am creating my first Java application that connects to MariaDB. I need to specify the database port number.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The *default* port number of MariaDB is 3306. It is the same as MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

The default port number for both MySQL and MariaDB is 3306, but you can change it as required with changing the `port` variable in the `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` file (on [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)/Ubuntu) or in the `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf` (on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)/[RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux)) and restarting the service ;)

Comment: The "port" line is outcommented by default (presumably means the port number is 3306).

Answer (score 1):

The default port number is 3306, the same as MySQL...if you have a trouble with port, I think you should check the firewall or if you need the remote access you can look at the bind address.