# Homebrew sql@5.7 The server quit without updating PID file in Catalina

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am trying to install mysql@5.7 through Homebrew in Mac OS Catalina following the link - https://gist.github.com/operatino/392614486ce4421063b9dece4dfe6c21 and when I try to start the server via `mysql.server start` ,  I get the error:

> Starting MySQL
>
> . ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/C02XL11SJGH8.pid).

I have attached the C02XL11SJGH8.err which is a very large file with the error logs. The latest error message in the file says:

> 2019-12-09T18:59:52.772975Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4800!

Please help in understanding the issue here.

[C02XL11SJGH8.err](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-8NH2G2icVJRNtnpjSI1Kmd_RA-gatG/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would help, I know catalina os already come preload it wit php7 so the path might be different.

[MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/8137439)

Comment: Thank you. However reinstalling mysql worked for me.