# How do I uninstall php apache and mysql so that I can use MAMP - MAC Lion

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I had mysql already installed on my macbook and hence decided to use macports to install php5. It got apache as a dependency and installed it too. Now I couldn't get php to work with mac. Searching all around decided to save some time by just installing MAMP. Before that I need to delete everything concerning php, apache and mysql. I have removed mysql by following this:

[How do you uninstall MySQL from Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x)

How do I remove php5 and apache from my mac?

Comment: Do you really need to delete all other instances of PHP and MySQL to use MAMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you do not need to remove them, just make sure Apache and MySQL aren't running, but port uninstall "application" should do the trick.

On a personal note I would shy away from MAMP and go with something like Zend Community server, MAMP can cause headaches if you need to use pear and/or pecl to install additional modules.

Comment: does the Zend Community edition include the Apache server as well

Comment: Yes, zend community server is a full lamp stack and more it installs all of it by default into /usr/local/zend (/usr/local/zend/bin  contains the apache/php binaries and /usr/local/zend/mysql contains the mysql binaries)

Comment: That worked. I installed the zend community edition. But I am unable to access mysql from my mysqlworkbench anymore. I can access it from a Terminal window though. I can't access the mysql server from a JDBC connection - tools such as DB Visualiser dont work.

Comment: And it looks like wordpress can't locate the database either. Could you help me understand why am I able to connect from the terminal only and not from any where else?