# uninstall mysql from mac not working

Tags: mysql, macos, uninstallation

I have done these steps:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
vim /etc/hostconfig and removed the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

But, now when I try to execute the command 'brew install mysql' is tells me 'mysql-5.6.10 already installed'

Anyone know the problem?

**

EDIT

**

Don't know if this will help diagnosing the problem, but...

What I'm trying to do is a fresh install with mysql_secure_installation. I could not log in to mysql with -uroot --password because it told me access was denied. After uninstalling using 'brew uninstall mysql' and then reinstallling with 'brew install mysql' I ran the mysql_secure_installation command. In the first step, where I'm supposed to enter the root password (press enter if there is no password) I pressed enter with a blank line and it told me access denied again.

Comment: reading the EDIT - you have now uninstalled mysql ?

Comment: @suspectus I did brew uninstall, then brew install, then the secure install command. I still ran into the access denied for root problem.

Comment: This may help-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os

Comment: See this post, it solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x

Answer (score 14):

Step 1: Uninstall MySQL.

Open the Terminal and type in: `cd /usr/local` , hit `enter`
Type in: `ls` , hit `enter`.

Verify that there are two items called `mysql` and `mysql-5.1.37-osx10.5-x86_64` (or similar).

These are the two items you want to delete.

Type in: `sudo rm mysql` , hit `enter`.

Type in: `sudo rm -rf mysql-5.1.37-osx10.5-x86_64` , and hit `enter`.

Step 2: Uninstall the MySQL Startup Item.

In Termainl type in: `cd /Library/StartupItems` , hit `enter`.

Type in: `ls`, hit `enter`.

Verify that there is an item called `MySQLCOM`. This is the item you want to delete.

Type in: `sudo rm -rf MySQLCOM` , and hit `enter`.

Enter your password when prompted.

EDIT **

Delete the config file in:

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

Also remove the enteries in:

```
/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist
```

Comment: I cd into /usr/local/ but these two items you list are not there.

Comment: Ok, then you should perform step 2 to remove other files. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: There is nothing in StartupItems either. There is a mysql directory in /usr/var/ and /usr/opt/. Does that matter?

Comment: Might be. Try deleting it. Also /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist delete the above file.

Comment: I deleted the file and did brew install. It says caveats are /etc/my.cnf may interfere

Answer (score 1):

I found a configuration file in my home directory, `~/.my.cnf`. It caused me an awful lot of problems, and it should be removed too.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to [this blog post](https://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com/2009/08/uninstall-mysql-on-mac-os-x.html), you may also need to remove the MySQL System Preferences at /Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL.prefPane