# Uninstall MySQL from Mac OS x

Tags: mysql, macos

I was trying to uninstall mysql from Mac. I was following the instruction given in [How do you uninstall MySQL from Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x)

In more detail, I execute the following command line-by-line:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*

sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM

sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*

vim /etc/hostconfig and removed the line MYSQLCOM=-YES- //(in my case, the line is MYSQLCOM=-NO)

rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*

sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*

sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
```

Everything worked fine, apart from trying to edit /etc/hostconfig by removing the line `MYSQLCOM=-NO`. It said the file is read-only. I have tried to change the permission of the file through Get Info, but I still cannot edit that file. Has any one encounter this as well and how to solve this?

If I keep the file hostconfig as it is, would this do any harm if I try to install mysql again?

Comment: `sudo -e /etc/hostconfig`

Answer (score 0):

I test and works this command in terminal:

Use mysqldump to backup your databases to text files!

Stop the database server

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
$ rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
$ sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql*
```