# XAMPP and MySQL installation on OSX

Tags: macos, xampp, mysql

I installed XAMPP. Then I installed MySQL. It appears that MySQL may have already been bundled with XAMPP?

So I apparently installed a second MySQL. I also installed the "MySQL startup" thing that makes MySQL start everytime I start my computer.

Now I have MySQL installed in two places. I can start and run MySQL on the one I knowingly installed but the MySQL located in "xamppfiles" gives me this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I'm not sure what to do. I appear to have a mysqld daemon running and I can't kill, it seems it restarts itself. I'm not sure of the proper way to get rid of one of the installations.

Comment: Just had this issue. I don't have a duplicate instance of MySql running, but killing XAMPP from the filesystem and putting in a new one fixed it all. Of course, you need to restore... everything

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the question is. MySQL is bundled in XAMPP. You are receiving that error because you are trying to start 2 instances of it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x) will help you uninstall mysql if that's what you are trying to do

Comment: My question is how to kill the daemon process that starts whenever I start my computer, how to uninstall ONE MySQL without uninstalling the other, and how to get rid of that error.