# MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' Mac osx

Tags: mysql, macos, passwords, root

Preface: Im aware that there are many related questions. I've combed through all that I could find but havent been able to fix this

I installed mysql for mac (Mac OS X 10.9 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive)

When I try to use the terminal I get

```
Blythes-MacBook-Air:bin blythe$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Blythes-MacBook-Air:bin blythe$
```

Or...

```
Blythes-MacBook-Air:bin blythe$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Blythes-MacBook-Air:bin blythe$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6474775/62576) will help.

Comment: unfortunately, i still couldnt get it to work, i edited my question to address that

Comment: The command you say you typed was `./mysql -u root`, but the output you show is for `mysqladmin`. Visit the link I provided again, and *carefully* read the answers posted (which include how to reset the root password from safe mode if needed).

Comment: Yeah-that was my mistake. For the safe mode approach, i get this error when i input: `mysql -u root`, I get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: The safe mode is supposed to be ongoing, but for me it ends with `150618 15:24:56 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Blythes-MacBook-Air.local.err'.
150618 15:24:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
150618 15:24:59 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/Blythes-MacBook-Air.local.pid ended`

Comment: So what does the `Blytes-MacBook-Air.local.err` file tell you?

Comment: How do I access that file?

Comment: The last comment you posted shows the exact location of the file. Do you not know how to find a directory or read a log file? (Just trying to ascertain your skill level.) When you started safe mode, did you `sudo` first as the instructions explained?

Comment: I cant get access to the error file, when i try to open it with the terminal (I have no idea why) and yes i used sudo. Is there a way to completely wipe mysql from my machine and just restart the whole installation process?

Comment: [How do you uninstall MySQL from OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1436425/62576).

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answers. I had mysql working on this machine before and i think i installed a version forgetting i already had it and it messes up everything. Im just gonna wipe everythign and start from scratch. Thanks again