# Cannot remove MySQL installed via brew on MacOS Mojave: No available formula or cask with the name "mysql"

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, macos-mojave, mysql-5.7

I installed MySQL 5.7.24 via Homebrew on MacOS Mojave v 10.14.4 per [this gist](https://gist.github.com/operatino/392614486ce4421063b9dece4dfe6c21). Now, I'm trying to remove it, but can't.

When I run `brew remove mysql` I get `Error: No available formula or cask with the name "mysql".`

I can run `brew uninstall --force mysql` and follow all the instructions from the post linked below, but I can't get `brew remove mysql` to work.

[How to uninstall MySQL 5.6 when installed by brew on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161511/how-to-uninstall-mysql-5-6-when-installed-by-brew-on-macos)

Here are the steps I'm following:

```
# stop mysql
brew services stop mysql@5.7

# force uninstall
brew uninstall --force mysql

# check for running instances
ps -ax | grep mysql | grep -v grep
# no running process to kill

brew remove mysql
brew cleanup
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*

# restart computer
```

After all of this, when I run `mysql --version` I get `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for osx10.9`.

Also, I thought that maybe I needed to specify `mysql@5.7` instead of just `mysql`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same exact problem

Comment: Yes using mysql@5.7 instead of mysql worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It works with the version number.

```
brew uninstall --force mysql@5.7
```

[screenshot**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfunF.png)