# libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib disaphere from /usr/local/mysql/lib/ MacOS

Tags: python, django, macos, mysql-python

I did `brew remove mysql`. After, i reinstall mysql from dmg again. But now i cant run my django project. It shows me:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/polinom/workspace/agents/eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/polinom/workspace/agents/eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

This does not help: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

And this does not help: `export DLYD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib`

I figured out that there is no file `/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`. Even here it is absent `/usr/local/mysql/lib/`. The only libs that sit in that folder is:

```
libmysqlclient.15.dylib    libmysqlclient_r.15.dylib  libndbclient.2.dylib       libndbclient.la
libmysqlclient.dylib       libmysqlclient_r.dylib     libndbclient.dylib
```

What do i do about that?

Comment: I did not understood the question

Comment: Is there a file named libmysqlclient.18.dylib under dir Cellar
`ls -al /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 imom0  admin  50 May 29 19:25 /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.5.24/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

Comment: No there is no such file. The only files that are there is the ones i wrote about in question. Looks like I have newer version libndbclient.2.dylib. Byt how do i connect it to python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed from a DMG this time, try looking in /usr/local/ for a file like

```
mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64
```

If you have that version or newer, `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` will be in there, and you just need to make sure that your symlink to /usr/local/mysql is correctly linking to that version. You may also have to add it to your path, the DMG installer did a horrible job of setting that stuff up for me.

If you have an earlier version than the one above, you may need to grab a newer copy of the DMG and reinstall. Hope this helps!

Comment: I just figured out by my self that i had wrong version of MySQL server. I installed 5.2 but suppose to 5.5.25. But i steel have a problem. `/usr/local/mysql/lib//libmysqlclient.18.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture`

Comment: Did you try looking at the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677591/cant-load-mysqlclient-18-dylib-into-python-on-mac-os-lion)? Seems like a similar issue at this point.

Comment: I could not find appropriate.

Comment: Try using ```arch -x86_64 python``` and ```arch -i386 python``` to run your django project. If one of those works and the other one gives you this error, then you need to repair the default python architecture. It may have gotten messed up if the brew version and the DMG version of mysql were different architectures.

Comment: I resolved that. Just installed 64 bit version of MySQL. Thanks for help!